# Does Skirmish apply to both attacking and defending?

Tags: keyforge

We're a bit confused about the Skirmish ability. The helper text on Quixo the "Adventurer" says the following:

> Skirmish. *(When you use this creature to fight, it is dealt no damage in return).*

We're confused about when a character is "fighting" for the purposes of this ability. Is that when it is attacking, defending, or both?

Comment: I think the confusion here is because of MTG. There are never any "attackers" or "defenders." link64 has the right idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No, Skirmish is only active on attacking**

You can only **Fight** on your turn. This means that **Skirmish** is only active when you select that creature to **Fight** as an action, negating any damage you would be dealt. 
If a creature with skirmish is targeted with a Fight action by an opponent, it will still take damage.

From the official [rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/51/f9/51f978e8-a62f-4a53-a246-912893396a05/keyforge_rulebook_v7_for_webcompressed.pdf):

> Any ready creature of the active house may fight. When a creature
>   is used to fight, its controller chooses one eligible creature controlled
>   by the opponent as the target of the attack. Each of the two creatures
>   deals an amount of damage equal to its power (the value to the left
>   of the card’s title) to the other creature